# How do I get every permutation in two totally unrelated tables with t-sql

Tags: t-sql, join

I have two tables that are indirectly related by another table

> TableA - ID, SomeFieldA
>
> TableB - ID, SomeFieldB
>
> TableAB - IDA, IDB, SomeFieldAB

I have to generate data from the ground up.  So I've put some data in TableA, and I've put some data in TableB.  The problem is, I need to insert data into TableAB now, and I don't know how to generate a script that will do all the permutations of TableA and TableB together.

For instance:

Table A has two records:

> 1, 'A'
>
> 2, 'AA'

Table B has two records:

> 3, 'B'
>
> 4, 'B'

I want to insert the following data into TableAB:

> 1, 3, 'first perm'
>
> 1, 4, 'second perm'
>
> 2, 3, 'third perm'
>
> 2, 4, 'fourth perm'

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: @Joseph said `Thanks, I knew it was something easy, I just was trying to JOIN and I was just making it too complicated.`  You need to join to make this work!  The answer you commented in uses a JOIN, it is an old sytle `FROM A, B`, see my answer for the same join using current SQL join syntax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use the **ancient** join syntax:  `FROM A, B`, use a proper join:

```
DECLARE @TableA table (Col1 varchar(5), Col2 varchar(5))
DECLARE @Tableb table (Col1 varchar(5), Col2 varchar(5))

INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES ('a','a')
INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES ('aa','aa')

INSERT INTO @TableB VALUES ('b','b')
INSERT INTO @TableB VALUES ('BB','BB')

SELECT
    *
    FROM @TableA
        CROSS JOIN @TableB
    ORDER BY 1
```

OUTPUT

```
Col1  Col2  Col1  Col2
----- ----- ----- -----
a     a     b     b
a     a     BB    BB
aa    aa    b     b
aa    aa    BB    BB

(4 row(s) affected)
```

this will also produce the same result set:

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM @TableA
        JOIN @TableB ON 1=1
    ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 INSERT TableAB
 SELECT A.ID 'IDA', B.ID 'IDB'
      , A.SomeFieldA+" "+B.SomeFieldB  'SomeFieldAB' 
 FROM A, B
```

A join without any conditions does all the permutations

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something easy, I just was trying to JOIN and I was just making it too complicated.

Comment: Never use that syntax! Maintainers won't know if you indtended a cross join or not. You should always use the explict joins especially when doing cross joins. Very bad practice to use implicit joins.

Comment: I'm used to TSQL way of doing things, not ANSI syntax... but I agree it's a valid concern.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this:

```
select
    a.*, b.*
from
    a, b
```

This will do a [cross join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690.aspx) which will give you all possible combinations.

From there, it's simple to use that within the context of an INSERT statement to populate your AB table.

Comment: implicit joins, bad - select * bad. Two poor practices in one piece of code, very bad.